# docker-compose up apache does not start

Tags: javascript, java, docker, apache, docker-compose

I'm trying to run a project. The logs seems ok, but i can't reach my https://localhost.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.5'

services:
    ## Reverse proxy Apache pour avoir un contexte https ISO prod
    apache:
        image: xxx:2.4.52-alpine
        container_name: office-4e28-apache
        network_mode: "host"
        volumes:
            - ./images/apache/configs/httpd.conf:/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
            - ./images/apache/configs/site.conf:/usr/local/apache2/conf/extra/site.conf
            - ./images/apache/configs/xxx.local.crt:/usr/local/apache2/ssl/xxx.local.crt
            - ./images/apache/configs/xxx.local.key:/usr/local/apache2/ssl/xxx.local.key
```

when I run `docker-compose up apache`

there is no port 443 occupied (or even 80),
I tried to see if it work, but the command

```
sudo netstat -tulpn
```

doesn't return our port.

I see warnings like

```
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

into the logs, but they don't have to be blocking.

Comment: What's actually in your image; do you have the coresponding Dockerfile?  Why do you use `network_mode: host` to disable Docker networking?

Comment: I don't really know, the project is quite complex and I'd just start to work with.
Nevertheless,

to replace by : 

        network_mode: "bridge"
        ports: 
            - 80
            - 443

does not work eather.

Comment: To put a binding 

8080:80
8443:443 

solved the problem

Comment: I use Portmapping like this: https://codefile.io/f/FYHOoYblP1
Works like a charme